# Pass external variable to function to sove with lsode in octave

Tags: function, octave, external

I have a function that I want to solve with lsode, like that:

```
function f = fcn(x,t)
  % Set spring stiffness and mass
  k = 500;
  m = 5;

  % Assign function
  f1 = x(2);
  f2 = -(k/m)*x(1);
  f = [f1; f2];
 endfunction
```

And this is the script that call this function:

```
% Initial value
x0 = [0.2, 0];

%time
t = linspace(0,1,500);

[X] = lsode (@fcn, x0, t);
plot(t,X(:,1));
```

Now, I want to loop this script, but every time I want a different value of "k". The function to be solved with lsode must accept only "x" and "t" as argument, then I can't put "k" on the argument-list.

I can't use an anonymous function, because the real function that I'm studying is more complicated (not just a linear oscillator).

Comment: I'm a little confused why you can't create an anonymous function that simply wraps your *other* function

Comment: That's because my function is not linear, I have many "if-else" statement inside, and I cant put it on an anonymous function.

Comment: You can create an anonymous function that *calls* your "non-linear" function. You don't have to worry about re-implementing your entire function as an anonymous function

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer, but I found a solution: I add the constants to the x_0 vector, and add functions equal to zero inside the function to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old, but I'd like to add an answer I found - essentially a working example of what @Suever described. Here's the code (thanks Jana!), copied & formatted in case the link breaks:

"Test.m" calls the function file "ODE.m"

**Content of "Test.m"**

```
clear;
clc;

t = linspace (0, 50, 10);       % Time interval for integration
y0 = [ 4; 1.1; 4 ];             % Initial condition for Y(0)
B=[77.27 8.375e-06 0.161];      % Additional fixed parameters used in ODE
funct=@(y0,t)ODE(y0,t,B);       % create a function to supply to LODE
y = lsode (funct, y0, t)        % Call LODE to solve
```

**Content of "ODE.m"**

```
function y = ODE (x, t, B)

y = zeros (3,1);

y(1) = B(1) * (x(2) - x(1)*x(2) + x(1) - B(2)*x(1)^2);
y(2) = (x(3) - x(1)*x(2) - x(2)) / B(1);
y(3) = B(3)*(x(1) - x(3));

endfunction
```

A short description of the steps:

1. Create your ODE function definition using all the arguments you'll want to pass to it, something like `ode_func( x, t, param1, param2, ... )`.
2. Create an anonymous function that only takes arguments of the format (x,t), but the definition of this anonymous function *is your ODE function with real/defined parameter values passed in*.
3. Call `lsode` with the anonymous function handle.

The link, for reference: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2019-12/msg00131.html